# sending serialization file via sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, file-upload, client-server

`System.out.println("Java is awesome!");`

Pardon my enthusiasm; I just can't believe how powerful Java is, what with its ability to not only save objects (and load them), but also with its main purpose, to send them over a network. This is exactly what I must do, for I am conducting a beta-test. In this beta-test, I have given the testers a version of the game that saves the data as Objects in a location most people don't know about (we are the enlightened ones hahaha). This would work fine and dandy, except that it isn't meant for long-term persistence. But, I could collect their `record.ser` and `counter.bin` files (the latter tells me how many Objects are in `record.ser`) via some client/server interaction with sockets (which I know nothing about, until I started reading about it, but I still feel clueless). Most of the examples I have seen online (this one for example: http://uisurumadushanka89.blogspot.com/2010/08/send-file-via-sockets-in-java.html ) were sending the File as a stream of bytes, namely some ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream. This is exactly what my current version of the game is using to save/load GameData.

Sorry for this long-winded intro, but do you know what I would have to do (steps-wise, so I can UNDERSTAND) to actually send the whole file. Would I have to reconstruct the file byte-by-byte (or Object-by-Object)?

Comment: You don't send the file but you send the serialized object itself. So underneath the ObjectOutputStream use your output stream of server socket.

Comment: I wish this was an answer, so I could upvote it and mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple, actually. Just make your objects serializable, and create an ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream that are connected to whatever underlying stream you have, say FileInputStream, etc. Then just write() whatever object you want to the stream and read it on the other side.

Heres an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/ReadingBasicDataFromanObjectStream.htm) for you.

For sockets it will be something like

```
ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
```

Comment: I have already done that first part: making the Objects serializable. In fact, that is how the GameData is stored on the computer; as serialized Objects. Do you know if there would be any way of tracking who is sending the GameData to me (since anyone on the Internet would then be able to do it)?  Oh, and I have never messed with client-server interaction or Sockets.

Comment: This question is more of an advice-related one: if the beta-tester's machine is sending me the GameData (which it will) to my computer, does that make my computer the Server and theirs the Client? //My computer is going to be writing their GameData to a database.

Comment: How can anyone send data to your socket. Socket = IP + port which is very specific to you. If the beta-tester's machine is sending you the data they are the server and you are the client.

Comment: Tell me, @Aniket Thakur, how are scores to games that are played online saved? (In terms of client-server)

Comment: Client-Server is relative terminology. When you say you are playing game online it means you are playing game on some server(your computer being the client). Now you are saving  beta-tester's machine is sending you some data which means that you(as a client) will ask the machine(server) to provide you game data. Note you are not the only one(client) playing the game and hence not the only one fetching the game data. Finally you say you are storing the data you fetched in some database. This will again make you the client and the infrastructure where you database is hosted as your server.

Comment: Note if the database is on localhost, platform for server and client is the same but the applications(behaving as server  and client) are different. To be a bit more technical server will always be listening to clients request. So in future if you get confused always ask yourself this question who is sending the request and who is processing that request.

Comment: Generally Connection at server end is what we call passive connection as it is initiated by the request sent by the client whereas connection at the client end is what we call active one because client actively puts request to the server.

Comment: I take it that what I am proposing to do would be bad practice, then? //The reason being not only what you said about the servers always listening for the only client, my computer, but now I have to consider EVERY LAST FREAKING PORT THAT ANY BETA-TESTER MIGHT BE USING!! (Scratch that, any number above 49151 is fair game: http://www.iana.org/form/ports-services)

Answer (score 0):

Java Serialization is an immensely powerful protocol. `java.io.ObjectOutputStream` and `java.io.ObjectInputStream` are the higher level classes which of course are wrapped with the lower level classes such as `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`. My question is why do you wish to read the file byte by byte when the entire file can be read in `Objects`.

Here is a good explanation of the procedure.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.html

Comment: Reading the file byte-by-byte was never my intention.