# Sending the IP address via two-way client-server interaction in Java

Tags: java, client-server, ip-address

I am trying to write a Java program that will send the data from a beta-tester's computer to mine. I used serialization to save the data to their computer, and now I am needing to fetch it and store it in the database. For this, I will need their IP address. (I will also be needing it for generating a userID for them.) It is because, in doing all this, I would be the client ([sending serialization file via sockets in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668025/sending-serialization-file-via-sockets-in-java)) and they would be the server. Of course, in client-server interaction, I would need to know their IP address. To circumvent that, I have decided to have them be the client (and request MY IP address, which is known, or some other information), and then I, as server, would request their IP address. When I have their IP address, I can request the information from them and store it onto the database.

Any suggestions as to how to go about this?

Comment: You can write a program that waits for data to be send to it, no need to jump through hoops.

Comment: This would only involve one client and one server, right? Also, would you even have to know the IP addresses of the servers (or their host names: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)?

//Although I have to say, this is genius, and will get my +1.

Comment: It's normal client/server architecture, any webserver (and many, many other applications) works like that. Wait for connection, handle it (e.g. fork), wait for the next.

Comment: But then, that would make you the server that is requesting data, right? //I am sorry for this, but I have no classroom exposure to this client-server interaction thing....

Comment: No. The names "Server" and "Client" have nothing to do with who receives or expects data, only who will initate the communication. The server is listening and waiting for connections, the client connects to it.

Comment: There is no need to request or send an IP address anywhere in a TCP conversation. TCP already transports the source address with each data segment. See [`Socket.getInetAddress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress()) and friends.

Comment: `this->shouldBeAnswer();` returns true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a program that will listen for connections on a certain port, and handle the data that is sent to it. The program that will sent data will have to know either a hostname or an ip address to initiate a connection to that program.

The program listening for connections is the server, the program initiating the connection is the client. Nothing to do with who sends data.

Comment: `this->isGoodAnswer();` User [Aniket Thakur][someUser] had me worried here (see the link to the question I posted in my question). I linked his name so that he could see this. 

[someUser]: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2396539/aniket-thakur/

Comment: That way, I can just have this program run AT ALL TIMES, listening for the data. As for getting their IP address (this won't be the only way I might generate for the user a userID), we could just do something like what is talked about [here][firstLink] , right?

[firstLink]: http://www.codereye.com/2010/01/get-real-ip-from-request-in-java.html/

Comment: Keep in mind that IP addresses can and will change. My ISP for example regulary reassigns my IP (consumer, not business contract).